# Why is expect's interact command not working?

Tags: scripting, expect

I am trying to automate gdb with expect. My script will start gdb, do some initialisation, and then pass the control to the user. Expect's `interact` command seems like the perfect tool for the job.

Now consider:

```
$ echo "spawn gdb
    expect \"(gdb) \"
    send \"help\r\"
    expect \"(gdb) \"
    interact" | expect -
```

On my machines, this scriptlet spawns gdb, issues the help command, as expected. But then it immediately exits the script and returns me to the bash prompt. I would expect the user to stay within gdb and be able to issue commands.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Are you running on Windows?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`interact` will get its input from `expects` standard input, which is the pipe to `echo` now closed.

You can write it instead (ksh/zsh/bash syntax):

```
expect <(echo "spawn gdb
  expect \"(gdb) \"
  send \"help\r\"
  expect \"(gdb) \"
  interact" )
```

That's still fed via a pipe, but this time, the pipe is given as a path argument to `expect` so expect's stdin is not affected.

In this case though, the obvious may to write it would be:

```
expect -c '
  spawn gdb
  expect "(gdb)"
  send "help\r"
  expect "(gdb) "
  interact'
```

`expect` like `sh` and most shells allow passing inline scripts with `-c`.

If you still need to pass the output of a command (like `echo` in your case), you can do it with `-c` as well with:

```
expect -c "$(echo...)"
```

That means however that contrary to the pipe approaches `expect` won't start until that command has finished.

BTW, here, you could use a `.gdbinit`  file instead or `-ix` option to `gdb`, you don't really need `expect`.

Comment: Thanks, it does make complete sense indeed. Could you please elaborate (or point to documentation) on the <() construction? I don't know it, and it's hard to google!

Comment: Also, yes I know about -ix but my real script is much more complex and in this case, I need the flexibility of expect. Good suggestion though.

Comment: @NicolasBonnefon. That's called _process substitution_, a ksh feature. Plenty of questions and answers on it on U&L

Comment: @NicolasBonnefon @StéphaneChazelas I have been able to avoid escaping the quotation marks by using the construct
`expect <(cat <<- 'EOF'
    ...
    EOF
)`

Comment: why so convoluted?  why not just write a `#!/usr/bin/expect -f`` script?

Comment: @cas, the OP is invoking expect as part of a _shell_ script, having to manage a separate _expect_ script would probably not be simpler.